# Having difficulty targeting the specific show more button, if clicked, shows hidden text of all testimonials, not just the one im clicking on

Tags: javascript, foreach

So what I'm trying to do is have a few testimonial cards displayed. With a show more/show less button. On click I want the text of that specific testimonial to show more/show less.
But at the moment my function is making all the testimonials show more/show less text. Please help, I don't know what I'm missing.

```js
const testimonialCards = document.querySelectorAll('#feedback-text'); //returns nodelist
const testimonialArray = Array.from(testimonialCards); //converts nodelist to array
const showMoreButton = document.querySelectorAll('.js-show-more');
const showMoreButtonArray = Array.from(showMoreButton);

//looping through the testimonial cards
testimonialArray.forEach(e => {
  //looping through buttons array
  showMoreButtonArray.forEach(t => {

    //adding onclick method to the buttons
    t.addEventListener('click', function() {

      //conditional to check if the hidden exists, if so so, remove it and add the show all class etc.
      if (e.classList.contains('excerpt-hidden')) {
        e.classList.remove('excerpt-hidden');
        e.classList.add('showAllContent');
        showMoreButton.innerText = "Show Less";
      } else {
        e.classList.add('excerpt-hidden');
        e.classList.remove('showAllContent');
        showMoreButton.innerText = "Show More";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/*Css for show more text and show less using the height of the text container*/

.js-show-more {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: unset;
  color: #b83426;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*truncating text*/

.excerpt-hidden {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 65px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.showAllContent {
  height: auto;
  overflow: initial;
  -webkit-line-clamp: none;
}
```

```html
<!--This is my testimonial card, I would have about 8 cards on pageload-->

<testimonial class="testimonial-card" flag="sa.svg">

  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p class="excerpt-hidden expanded-text" id="feedback-text">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <button class="js-show-more">Show More</button>

</testimonial>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
const testimonialCards = document.querySelectorAll('#feedback-text'); //returns nodelist
const showMoreButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-show-more');

//looping through buttons array
showMoreButtons.forEach((t, i) => {

  //adding onclick method to the buttons
  t.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const e = testimonialCards[i]

    // conditional to check if the hidden exists, if so so, 
    // remove it and add the show all class etc.
    if (e.classList.contains('excerpt-hidden')) {
      e.classList.remove('excerpt-hidden');
      e.classList.add('showAllContent');
      t.innerText = "Show Less";
    } else {
      e.classList.add('excerpt-hidden');
      e.classList.remove('showAllContent');
      t.innerText = "Show More";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*Css for show more text and show less using the height of the text container*/

.js-show-more {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: unset;
  color: #b83426;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*truncating text*/

.excerpt-hidden {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 65px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.showAllContent {
  height: auto;
  overflow: initial;
  -webkit-line-clamp: none;
}
```

```html
<testimonial class="testimonial-card" flag="sa.svg">

  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p class="excerpt-hidden expanded-text" id="feedback-text">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <button class="js-show-more">Show More</button>
</testimonial>

<testimonial class="testimonial-card" flag="sa.svg">
  <h4>Title 2</h4>
  <p class="excerpt-hidden expanded-text" id="feedback-text">
    It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
  <button class="js-show-more">Show More</button>

</testimonial>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**

- You are iterating over the `showMoreButton` for each testimonial. That is completely unnecessary and is the cause of the problem you are facing. Each testimonial has one button associated with it. You just need to iterate over the testimonials, get the button in the current testimonial and add the event listener on it.
- You don;t need to convert `NodeList` returned by `document.querySelectorAll` to an array. You can use `.forEach()` method with the `NodeList`.

**Solution**:

You could add a separate `click` listener on each button but there's a better way. You could take advantage of [Event Bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture).

Wrap all the testimonials in a wrapper `div` and add the `click` event on the wrapper element instead of on each button associated with each testimonial.

When a `click` event is triggered on the wrapper `div` element, take following steps:

1. Check if `Event.target` is a button.
2. If it is, get the parent element of the clicked button and then select the `#feedback-text` element.
3. Then toggle the `excerpt-hidden` and `showAllContent` classes on the selected `#feedback-text` element.
4. Finally, change the text of the clicked button.

Following code snippet shows an example with two testimonials.

```js
const testimonialWrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

testimonialWrapper.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const target = event.target;

  if (target.matches('.js-show-more')) {
    const p = target.parentElement.querySelector('#feedback-text');

    p.classList.toggle('excerpt-hidden');
    p.classList.toggle('showAllContent');

    target.textContent = 
        target.textContent == 'Show More' ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More';
  }
});
```

```css
.js-show-more {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: unset;
  color: #b83426;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.excerpt-hidden {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 65px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.showAllContent {
  height: auto;
  overflow: initial;
  -webkit-line-clamp: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <testimonial class="testimonial-card" flag="sa.svg">

    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="excerpt-hidden expanded-text" id="feedback-text">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <button class="js-show-more">Show More</button>

  </testimonial>

  <testimonial class="testimonial-card" flag="sa.svg">

    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="excerpt-hidden expanded-text" id="feedback-text">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <button class="js-show-more">Show More</button>

  </testimonial>
</div>
```